# How to sketch the following set $|z|=arg(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, graphing-functions

I want to sketch the following set:

Set of all those complex numbers which satisfy the following equation $$|z|=arg(z)$$

Efforts:

We are looking at those points in plane whose distance from origin is equal to the angle they subtends with respect to x axis.

arg(z) is multivalued

Points like $(\pi/2,0)$ , $(2\pi,0)$, $(-\pi,0)$ belongs to the set. But what are other points.

How to plot this set.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hint: use the polar form of complex numbers.

Comment: @AlessioDV let me try it. Say $z=r e^{i \phi}$ then we are looking those points for which $$r=\phi+ 2\pi k$$ right?

Comment: It should intuitively be a spiral (the angle and the magnitude increase together) and is in fact an Archimedean spiral

Comment: Thanks for the link. @AlessioDV

Comment: @StammeringMathematician One nice way to find it out is to note that the points of the set are those of the form $z=re^{ir}$, from which you can derive a parameterisation of a spiral.